# Is Xcode Source Editor Extension still supported by Xcode14?

Tags: xcode, xcode14

I try to prototype a Xcode plugin by following https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit/creating_a_source_editor_extension?language=objc but blocked for the first step as there is not an entry in the project template list for `Xcode Source Editor Extension`.

So is it an abandoned feature or should I do something to enable the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is available in Xcode version 14.
To get this option

1. We need to have our Xcode Project Open
2. Select File -> New -> Target
3. In the template section select MacOS category and the `Xcode Source Editor Extension`

Note: Without Step 1 when we select target it does nothing.

Reference:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Does the type of project in Step 1 matter?